# PHP - Yii - I can access model's data in a view file, but have the getUrl in its controller. How do i access this?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

PHP - Yii - I can access model's data in a view file, but have the getUrl in its controller. How do i access this?

basically, in yii, i have a model and controller set up. in the controller for a certain models (videos) i have a function called getUrl.

on the homepage i've edited the view to include the latest posts. i do this in **views/site/index.php** with:

```
    <?php $this->widget('LatestVideos'); ?>
```

and the LatestVideos widget has this code:

```
<?

Yii::import('zii.widgets.CPortlet');

class LatestVideos extends CPortlet {
public $title='Tags';
public $maxVideos = 20;
protected function renderContent() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->limit=$maxVideos;        
    $vids = Video::model()->findAll();
    foreach($vids as $video) {
        $link = Yii::app()->createUrl('video/view', array(
            'id'=>$video->id,
            'title'=>$video->video_title,
        ));
        echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $video->video_title . '</a>';
    }
```

as you can see, in that widget i get the info about latest videos by going straight from the widget to the model. i skip the controller. i need to access the controller to propperly access the getUrl function. how do i do this?

Comment: what is your getUrl function doing? giving a url for the video? are you storing that url in the table for videos? is there a db field called url for each video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your video model write following method...

```
public function getUrl(){
    return Yii::app()->createUrl('video/view', array(
        'id'=>$this->id,
        'title'=>$this->video_title,
    ));
}
```

and the LatestVideos widget has this code:

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CPortlet');
class LatestVideos extends CPortlet {
public $title='Tags';
public $maxVideos = 20;
protected function renderContent() {
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->limit=$maxVideos;        
$vids = Video::model()->findAll();
foreach($vids as $video) {
    echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($video->video_title), $video->url);
}
```

I think this is help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this`if (Yii::app()->controller) Yii::app()->controller->createUrl()`